# How to write the results of lidR grid_metrics to a georeferenced raster?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, lidar, lidr

I'm using the [lidR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/index.html) package to calculate LiDAR grid metrics (p.18 [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf)) for forestry applications. For example, the following calculates the mean elevation within a 20m cell:

```
library(lidR)

LASfile <- "/Users/aaron/Desktop/data/1958-08-53.laz"
lidar <- readLAS(LASfile)

l <- grid_metrics(lidar, mean(Z), 20)
```

I can plot the results using the following approach:

```
grid_metrics(lidar, mean(Z), 20) %>% plot
```

What is the proper method to write the grid metrics to a georeferenced raster (e.g. geotiff)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `lidR` package there is a function `as.raster` which is faster than `rasterFromXYZ`

```
r <- as.raster(l)
```

If `l` is several columns wide (more than one metric), the output is a `RasterStack` instead of a `RasterLayer`

Answer (score 5):

Since the output is a dataframe with X,Y coordinates and a value (V1) column, you can use `rasterFromXYZ` from the [`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package. Then write to GeoTIFF format using `writeRaster`, also from the `raster` package.

```
library(lidR)
library(raster)

LASfile <- "/Users/aaron/Desktop/temp/lidR_gridmetrics/1958-08-53.las"
lidar <- readLAS(LASfile)

l <- grid_metrics(lidar, mean(Z), 20) 

r <- rasterFromXYZ(l, crs='+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs ')
writeRaster(r, filename="/Users/aaron/Desktop/temp/lidR_gridmetrics/1958-08-53.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```